# Динамическое преобразование объекта в другой объект

Tags: javascript, node.js

Есть массив объектов которые подтягиваются с бд:

```
[ { objectType: 'evidence',
attributes:
 { firstName: 'Sergey',
   lastName: 'Vatz',
   gender: 'male',
   phone: '+380997546920',
   birthDate: '11.22.1995',
   email: 'wap2323@gmail.com' },
imageID: '507f1f77bcf86cd799439012',
type: 'personal_information' }]
```

При чем подобных объектов может быть неограниченное количество, проблема состоит в том что бы написать такой алгоритм который будет преобразовывать каждый объект `attributes` в элемент вида:

```
attributes: {
  firstName: { value: 'Sergey', required: false },
  lastName: { value: 'Vatz', required: false }
  gender: { value: 'male', required: false }
  phone: { value: '+380997546920', required: false }
  birthDate: { value: '11.22.1995', required: false }
  email: { value: 'wap2323@gmail.com', required: false }
}
```

Причем каждый последующий объект с бд, должен создавать новый объект `attributes` и динамически записывать `value` и `property` в новый объект. Гуру помогите пожалуйста. Всем добра)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Важно**, я использовал deepClone чтобы не осталось никаких ссылок в объектах которые в новых массивах, многие с этим ошибаются. Если бы не было клонирования, то, например, `arr[0].obj.a = 6`(в примере есть) изменил значения во всех массивах с 5 на 6. Это тонкий момент который лучше запомнить, он может привести к большому не понятному багу.

Как лучше копировать указано [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-deep-clone-an-object-in-javascript).

```js
let arr = [ 
  { 
    objectType: 'evidence',
    obj: {
      a: 5
    },
    attributes: { 
      firstName: 'Sergey',
      lastName: 'Vatz',
      gender: 'male',
      phone: '+380997546920',
      birthDate: '11.22.1995',
      email: 'wap2323@gmail.com',
      imageID: '507f1f77bcf86cd799439012',
      type: 'personal_information' 
    }
  }
]

let newArr1 = deepClone(arr.map(i => ({
  ...i,
  attributes: Object.keys(i.attributes).reduce((obj, attr) => 
    (obj[attr] = { 
      value: i.attributes[attr], 
      required: false 
    }, obj), {})
})))

// тот же код но упрощенный
let newArr2 = deepClone(arr.map(i => {
  const attributes = Object.keys(i.attributes).reduce((obj, attr) => {
    obj[attr] = { 
      value: i.attributes[attr], 
      required: false 
    }

    return obj
  }, {})
  
  return { 
    ...i,
    attributes
  }
}))

// теще один вариант
let newArr3 = deepClone(arr.map(i => {
  let attributes = {}
  for (let key in i.attributes)
    attributes[key] = {
      value: deepClone(i.attributes[key]), 
      required: false 
    }
  
  return { 
    ...deepClone(i),
    attributes
  }
}))

// значение останется 5, нет никаких связей с оригинальным массивом
arr[0].obj.a = 6

console.log(newArr1, newArr2, newArr3)

// глубокое копирование объекта, чтобы не было ссылок-объектов внутри клонируемого объекта
function deepClone (obj) {
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это выручило меня)

Comment: Не за что, обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Можно сделать вот так

```js
const arr = [{
  objectType: 'evidence',
  attributes: {
    firstName: 'Sergey',
    lastName: 'Vatz',
    gender: 'male',
    phone: '+380997546920',
    birthDate: '11.22.1995',
    email: 'wap2323@gmail.com'
  },
  imageID: '507f1f77bcf86cd799439012',
  type: 'personal_information'
}];

arr.forEach((m) => {
  Object.keys(m.attributes).forEach(a => {
    m.attributes[a] = {
      value: m.attributes[a],
      required: false
    }
  });
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, это выручило меня)

Comment: @SiergiejVatz, если ответ помог Вам - пометьте его галочкой)

Comment: у вас мутируется attributes у arr

Comment: @ИльяЗеленько да, мутирует. Возможно, ТС, не нужен оригинальный массив. В таком случае мой ответ подойдет.